# How do you change the language of video ads on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I live in the US, but I want everything online to be in French. I've changed both the language setting and location setting on both YouTube and the device itself, and it's worked with everything but the ads on YouTube, which remain in English. Is there a way to change these as well, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you tried changing the **Content location** setting at the very bottom of the page at Youtube.com? It would affect a lot more than just ads, but it might do what you’re asking for.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way: Use Adblock (if you are a free-to-browse person) or YouTube Red (if you are someone willing to spend a few bucks each month) to stop YouTube from displaying ads altogether.

Comment: The question was how to change the language of ads, not how to remove them.